# Usage of the word 'thence'

Tags: word-usage

can we use *thence* the way we use *therefore*. As when an occurence led by an action. For example: "my mom forbid me to go to Amy's house" thence I cannot go". Is this gramatically correct. *So the occurence is that I cannot go*.

Comment: Are you confusing *thence* with *thus*?

Comment: yes. *Thus*, *Therefore*, makes perfect sense to me. But I would like to know if *Thence* is also proper for this sort of context

Comment: You can use *hence* here although it is wee bit formal. I accept you can't use *thence* without sounding archaic but I can't why one is acceptable but not the other.

Comment: This would be easier had your Question been rendered in proper English and nevertheless, we can use "thence" roughly the way we use "therefore"

However, "my mom *forbade* me to go to Amy's house thence I cannot go" is not correct. That sentence needs "thus" not "thence".

Regardless of content, in no case could you correctly say "the occurence is that I cannot go".

Answer (score 3):

Well, technically *thence* carries that meaning ([wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thence#Adverb)), but like the others in the comments have said, *therefore* or *thus* are the preferred versions as *thence* is terribly archaic in both of its listed definitions.

Comment: Wiktionary only flags one sense of 'thence' as being archaic. Lexico, as the new answer says, has _as a consequence:
"studying maps to assess past latitudes and thence an indication of climate"_ which it flags as formal, not archaic. // Obviously, '; as a consequence' works in OP's example sentence, but not (with any punctuation we might try) 'thence'.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a necropost, but the correct usage of the word is something like "Then to X from a place previously mentioned".

To quote Harper Lee,

> ~He worked his way across the Atlantic to Philadelphia, thence to Jamaica, thence to Mobile, and up the Saint Stephens.

Another use is "in consequence".  What you mentioned is close to, but not the correct usage of the word.

By Oxford,

> studying maps to assess past latitudes and thence an indication of climate.

In this case, *thence* connects the two parts as a consequent result of the previous result.

Comment: *Thence* simply means “from there” — nothing more, nothing less. See [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/77509/2085) for other details and examples in modern use.